# Cant add text to webview text field with Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am trying to add text to a textfield (inside a webview) in Esprsso and I'm getting this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in evaluationEvaluation:
>   status: 13 value: {message=Cannot set the selection end} hasMessage:
>   true message: Cannot set the selection end

code:

```
textField.perform(webKeys("exmaple@test.com"));
```

when i'm just clicking on the textfield it works but when i'm trying to enter text it crashes.

Comment: Did you find the answer? I've been facing the same issue!! :(

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. My code works for Android 7.1.1 simulator but it fails on the Android 8.0 simulator.
I got it resolved by doing the following in the build.gradle.

1) Upgrade espresso library. 
I was on:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2')
```

Now it to:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0'
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.0')
```

2) After doing that, your app might not build. It might say it cannot find the test:runner:1.0.0
In that case, you need to add

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}
```

3) The following issue you might need to resolve is that it might complain about "versions for app (2x.x.x) and test app (2x.x.x) differ"
So I add the following in the gradle.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:2x.x.x'
}
```

4) Additional, you might need to make sure you have the Runner added.

```
defaultConfig {
        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```