# Espresso webView webkeys failures on the Android 8.0 simulator

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am running some test codes from Espresso Web

```
@Test
public void typeTextInInput_clickButton_SubmitsForm() {
    // Lazily launch the Activity with a custom start Intent per test.
    mActivityRule.launchActivity(withWebFormIntent());

    // Selects the WebView in your layout. If you have multiple WebView objects,
    // you can also use a matcher to select a given WebView,
    // onWebView(withId(R.id.web_view)).
    onWebView()
        // Find the input element by ID.
        .withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "text_input"))

        // Clear previous input and enter new text into the input element.
        .perform(clearElement())
        .perform(DriverAtoms.webKeys(MACCHIATO))

        // Find the "Submit" button and simulate a click using JavaScript.
        .withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "submitBtn"))
        .perform(webClick())

        // Find the response element by ID, and verify that it contains the
        // entered text.
        .withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "response"))
        .check(webMatches(getText(), containsString(MACCHIATO)));
}
```

It worked on the 7.1.1 simulator but not on the 8.0
I got the error message as

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in evaluationEvaluation: status: 13 value: {message=Cannot set the selection end} hasMessage: true message: Cannot set the selection end

if I change the code

```
element.
        .perform(clearElement())
        .perform(DriverAtoms.webKeys(MACCHIATO)) => perform(webClick())
```

Then it works. So I guess it can find the element just not perform the action.
Is there anything I need to change in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am facing the same issue. Please refer to this post in [Cant add text to webview text field with Espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571968/cant-add-text-to-webview-text-field-with-espresso/45761498#45761498)

My code works for Android 7.1.1 simulator but it fails on the Android 8.0 simulator as well.
I got it resolved by doing the following in the build.gradle.

1) Upgrade espresso library. 
I was on:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2')
```

Now it to:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0'
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.0')
```

2) After doing that, your app might not build. It might say it cannot find the test:runner:1.0.0
In that case, you need to add

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}
```

3) The following issue you might need to resolve is that it might complain about "versions for app (2x.x.x) and test app (2x.x.x) differ"
So I add the following in the gradle.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:2x.x.x'
}
```

4) Additional, you might need to make sure you have the Runner added.

```
defaultConfig {
        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works for me. I have been in the old version of android espresso for some time.

Comment: Facing the same issue, but this answer didn't solve it. Any other solution