# Android Espresso WebView webClick() and webKeys() does not trigger blur event on input field

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, android-espresso, blur

I'm trying to test a WebView using Espresso. The WebView contains some input fields and a button to continue to the next page. I am able to enter the text in the input fields. After leaving the input field a blur event should get called that performs some additional formatting and validation. However the blur event never gets called and therefore I cannot continue to the next page.

It looks like [webKeys()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/web/webdriver/DriverAtoms.html#webkeys) is just injecting some text and that [webClick()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/web/webdriver/DriverAtoms.html#webClick()) simply triggers a click event. That's probably why focus never changes and the blur event never gets called. When I physically press the input field myself the event does get triggered and I also see the Android input cursor. When the test case is running I don't see the cursor when text is entered in the input fields.

Is there a way to trigger the blur event programmatically or set focus to an element within the WebView using Espresso?

This is the code I'm using for inserting text.

```
public static void insertText(String label, String content)
{
    onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.XPATH, "//div[preceding::span[.='" + label + "']]/input")).perform(clearElement()).perform(webClick())
               .perform(webKeys(content));
}
```

**Edit:** Added relevant dependencies.

```
implementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.2.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.2.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-web:3.2.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.2.0"
```

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45822982/4079010

Comment: @RahulKhurana not sure how that is going to help as I'm not getting the error that's mentioned in that question. I'm also not testing on an emulator. However I updated my question and added the relevant dependencies.

Comment: What solution did you find for tiggering events? I am trying to trigger `onChange` on an `input`

Answer (score 3):

You can send any javascript to your Web view.

Every "atom" (`webKeys` is one of atoms) is just some javascript code, which is sent to your Web View. `webKeys` atom probably sends `keypress` events, which does not fire `focus/blur/change` events in browsers. This is sort of standard browsers behaviour for userspace code dispatched events.

As you can manually trigger keypress, you can trigger focus too etc. You can create and dispatch focus by using:

```
onWebView().withElement(...)
        .perform(SimpleAtom("function(elem) {\n" +
                   "var e = document.createEvent('Event');\n" +
                   "e.initEvent('focus', true, true);\n" +
                   "elem.dispatchEvent(e);}"
                ))
```

This should set focus to given element. You are sending function, which is then invocated with yours element as first argument.

You should create some classes like `SetFocusAtom` or `RemoveFocusAtom` etc. which will extend `SimpleAtom` instead of copy&paste whole javascript everywhere.

Be aware:

- **You can send any javascript to WebView, but you probably don't want.** You're free to edit values of currently invisible inputs etc. You're writing UI test, so you could test only visible parts of UI. Original atoms (`webClick`, `webKeys` etc.) are checking items for actual visibility. You should everytime use some of original atom or at least match for visibility.
- **You can do only what is possible in userspace Javascript.** There are some limitations. Like current question for example. In projects with complex WebViews, you should consider using UIAutomator or some implementation of Selenium (using chromedriver). Espresso-web is not "acting as real user would". This is not achievable by javascript injections only. Chromedriver is much powerfull in user-like acting.
- My answer is not generic. Sometimes you don't need to set `focus/blur` on inputs. Sometimes you want to send `change` event for example, which is also not triggered by `webKeys`.